# Validate title and body of GitHub Pull Request

Tags: git, github, github-api, pull-request, github-app

Is there way to validate the title and body of a GitHub Pull Request. I know that we can use Pull Request Template to prepopulate the pull Request message. Also GitHub does provide [WebHooks](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/) , [Checks API](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.20/user/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-status-checks#checks) which run against each commit.

But I'm looking for some way in which we can **validate the message body of Pull Request**(like, look for the presence of a valid JIRA ID) when a the contributor hits the **"Send Pull Request"** button and based on validation **accept** or **reject** the Pull Request.

I am thinking of implementing this through a **GitHub App**, which will be installed on an org-level repo.

I am not concerned about checking the commits.

I came across [ContentReferenceEvent](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#contentreferenceevent) which seems to provide a similar but incomplete feature where **only the URL** is read and `content_reference` events are triggered. I was hoping this to provide a way for getting the title and body of PullRequest too.

However, [Using content attachments](https://developer.github.com/apps/using-content-attachments/) says that this feature is only for beta use:

> **Note:** The Content Attachments API is currently in public beta and only
>   available for use with GitHub Apps. Features and requirements may
>   change at any time during this period.

As this is in beta phase, I cannot use this feature.

Please let me know what other alternatives are out there OR how can I implement this on my own, if nothing like that already exists.

Comment: One close vote already received for marking this question as Off-Topic. I beg for clarification. Which criterion/critera of https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic does this question satisfy. Please do mention the point number.

Comment: Hi Asif. I am in need of this exact feature. Did you eventually build this as a GitHub  App? Thanks.

Comment: Following up, any update to this?